# GRUB menu not loading after restart

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, grub

I accidentally restored BIOS on my dell Inspiron 5559 which was dual booting earlier with Windows 10 and Ubuntu-16.04. After restoring BIOS, GRUB got deleted which I repaired using 'boot-repair' .  I restarted the system and GRUB successfully loaded.  I wanted to make sure that windows was okay or not so I booted in the windows. Problem arose when I restarted from windows. GRUB was nowhere to be seen after restarting from windows. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

- Get a usb with a live OS installation.
- Boot into Rescue mode
- Run these following commands to install grub onto your hardrive.

  `update-grub`

  `grub-install /dev/sdX`

After these steps you should be able to boot into grub.